# Javascript built-in documentation/help functionality

Tags: javascript, documentation, built-in

When writing code in Java, the nice thing is that the IDE provides code-completion and auto suggestions mainly because Java is strongly typed language and therefore static type analysis can be achieved. When writing code with any library, or even with the standard JDK for that matter, I can easily reason about APIs (return types, and input parameters, etc.) for any given method of a class. If I need further understanding, I read up on standard JDK documentation or documentation for that given library.

With python, since the language is dynamically typed, type inference happens at runtime, for me, it's often a bit trickier to reason about APIs because there is no compile time checking. However, I can still be as productive because python offers built-in things such as the "dir" command which tells me everything about a particular object (methods, magic methods, fields, etc.) and also the built-in "help" command provides documentation at the command line for any type/class/module.

Does Javascript provide anything similar to python in that regard? I'd like to be more productive when coding in Javascript, but tabbing back and forth betweeen documentation and writing code has slowed me down a bit. Is there a better suggested approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime text has a plugin called docblockr that works quite well. However, many IDE's (eclipse/intellij/sublime text are my favorite three) support this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Languages and IDEs are two different things. A language can be supported by multiple IDEs, and it is possible for an IDE to support multiple languages. So, there is no such thing as "the Java IDE" -- there are many IDEs that support Java. The same applies to Javascript.

What you need to do is just search for an IDE (and/or plug-in for that IDE) that supports the features that you would like for your chosen language.

I happen to be partial to the eclipse IDE, which supports many, many different languages, including Javascript. [Here is a link](http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-javascript-web-developers/heliosr) that might be helpful. But there are many other choices out there. The choice is up to you.